# Print out post-order from a stack in Java

Tags: java, stack

I am doing stack and recursion. I am able to print out the preorder from 1 to 3. I am stuck on how can i make another loop so it will pop everything off the stack and then print the postorder. Output should look like

```
preorder
1
2
3
postorder
3
2
1

public class stack {
    public static void iterative(int from, int to) {
        for ( ; from <= to; from++ ) {
            System.out.print("pre: " + from + "\n"); //This is will print out the preorder
        }
       //Another loop to print out postorder?
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    stack.iterative(1, 3);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not really a stack. It's just a loop. Simply reverse the order and print `to` instead of `from`

Answer (score 1):

Just traverse the stack in from last...

```
for(;to>=from;to--)
```

Comment: Actually it should be `for(;from<=to;to--)` since `to<=from` is almost always `false` (unless `to==from` originally)

Comment: if from<=to then it will be false because after print out pre, from = 4, to = 3, so 4 can't be less than 3. Any idea?